# Hyperlink inside div with a class assigned inside a tag in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, class-design

Currently I am trying to implement my first HTML5 application, but I am having some general issues regarding HTML/CSS, specially using header tag.

Usually I put the main tag at the beginning of the CSS rule, therefore I could control each property and to don't mix any of them.

Right now I have this CSS code:

```
header div.followUs { float:right; font:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;    color:#B2B2B2; font-style:italic }
header div.followUs a,a:link,a:active,a:visited { color:orange }

header nav { clear:right; float:right; margin-top:20px }
header nav ul li { float:left; margin-right: 25px; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold }
header nav ul li:last-child { margin-right: 0 }
header nav ul li a { text-decoration:none }
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<header>
<div class="header-inner clearfix">
    <h1 class="logo">Client KickOff</h1>
    <div class="followUs">Segue-nos no <a href="#">Twitter</a> and <a href="#">Facebook</a>.</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/html/">Notícias</a></li>
            <li><a href="/html5/">Quem Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="/css/">Os Nossos Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="/css3/">O Nosso Portefólio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/js/">Contacte-nos!</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

It is giving the same color as the div with the followUs class applied to the navigation items.

Any ideias?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What "it" is giving the same color?

Comment: As an aside, unless you have additional elements besides `div` that will have class `followUs` or some reason for extra specificity that's not show in the above, just use `.followUs` rather than `div.followUs`. Adding the element just [slows down the selectors](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/). `nav li` and `nav a` will probably be sufficient as well and much faster to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header div.followUs a,a:link,a:active,a:visited { color:orange }
```

will literally mean this:

```
header div.followUs a { color: orange }
a:link { color: orange }
a:active { color: orange }
a:visited { color: orange }
```

So your links in the navigation are matching to the single `a:link` rule, since it is not specified to be within the header and followUs division.

You need to have the `header div.followUs` in front of each of the `a:` selectors. Although, you should just remove the extra `a:` selectors because the initial `header div.followUs a` will already cover all forms.

Comment: Oh I got it!

Thanks a lot! Really thought of when having it all in one line, followed by the main objects it would associate it, but it makes sense in this way, as we should assign every single object the way we want it.

Thanks a lot! (first post and this seems to be a great community - and very fast!)

Answer (score 0):

`header div.followUs a,a:link,a:active,a:visited { color:orange }` here is the problem
you have a link set up to orange an clearly li tags you have links, `remove a:link`

Comment: Hello rmagnum2002 but I want to use the li's with links.

I've followed the reply from animuson. Thanks anyway!

Comment: no problem, I am just glad that you solved your problem here. take care.